# How to put the value in dictionary which contains number within double quotes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, lambda

I have created a dictionary from the response which I have received. But I want to the values which contains numbers to be within the double quotes.

```
{'id': '262', 
'model_name': 'string', 
'endpoint_name': 'string', 
'data_capture_location': 'string', 
'baseline_job_output_location': 'string', 
'monitoring_output_location': 'string', 
'schedule_expression': 'cron(0 0/23 ? * * *)', 
'instance_type': 'string', 
'instance_volume_size': 20, 
'baseline_max_runtime_seconds': 3600, 
'monitor_max_runtime_seconds': 3600, 
'pipeline_type': 'byom_data_quality_monitor', 
'baseline_data': 'SageRltArtifacts/iris_binomial_baseline_DQ.csv'}
```

before passing these dictionary to the respective function I need to change all the single quotes to double quotes. For that I used json.dump,
but the 'instance_volume_size','baseline_max_runtime_seconds','monitor_max_runtime_seconds'  which contains number also needs to be inside the double quotes. But I am not able to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Here I would suggest you to use this approach:

```
import json


def dict_to_str(a):
    if isinstance(a,dict):
        for i in a:
            if not isinstance(a[i],dict):
                a[i]=str(a[i])
            else:
                dict_to_str(a[i])
    else:
        return

a = {'id': '262', 
'model_name': 'string', 
'endpoint_name': 'string', 
'data_capture_location': 'string', 
'baseline_job_output_location': 'string', 
'monitoring_output_location': 'string', 
'schedule_expression': 'cron(0 0/23 ? * * *)', 
'instance_type': 'string', 
'instance_volume_size': 20, 
'baseline_max_runtime_seconds': 3600, 
'monitor_max_runtime_seconds': 3600, 
'pipeline_type': 'byom_data_quality_monitor', 
'baseline_data': 'SageRltArtifacts/iris_binomial_baseline_DQ.csv'}


dict_to_str(a)
print(json.dumps(a, default=str))
```

Output:

```
{
   "id":"262",
   "model_name":"string",
   "endpoint_name":"string",
   "data_capture_location":"string",
   "baseline_job_output_location":"string",
   "monitoring_output_location":"string",
   "schedule_expression":"cron(0 0/23 ? * * *)",
   "instance_type":"string",
   "instance_volume_size":"20",
   "baseline_max_runtime_seconds":"3600",
   "monitor_max_runtime_seconds":"3600",
   "pipeline_type":"byom_data_quality_monitor",
   "baseline_data":"SageRltArtifacts/iris_binomial_baseline_DQ.csv"
}
```

Comment: Good one. I had written it as `for (i, v) in a.items(): if isinstance(v, int):  a[i] = str(v)`. Then json.dumps().

Comment: That's a good solution too, I have written above solution for nested dictionary too :D.